# Query filter object only working once - extbase 6.2

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In my extbase repository I've built a similar query function as described in this tutorial: [this](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html) and it was using a filter object, `$demand`.
So I created a class for my filter as well in order to work with an object in fluid.

It works, but only once - I can change something, click on "Filter" and it works.
But if I change something again and click on "Filter" it jumps back to the previous values and nothing changes.

I feel like this might have something to do with caching, but I'm not sure.
When I debug the filter object it doesn't show my the debug code after the second click on "Filter" because that's what it does when nothing has changed I noticed.

**What can I do to change my filter settings as many times as I want?**

My filter class:

```
class AppointmentFilter extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * future
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $future = 1;

    /**
     * booked
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $booked = 2;

    /**
     * student
     *
     * @var \vendor\extension\Domain\Model\Student
     */
    protected $student = NULL;

    /**
     * expertise
     *
     * @var \vendor\extension\Domain\Model\Expertise
     */
    protected $expertise = NULL;

    function getFuture() {
        return $this->future;
    }

    function getBooked() {
        return $this->booked;
    }

    function getStudent() {
        return $this->student;
    }

    function getExpertise() {
        return $this->expertise;
    }

    function setFuture($future) {
        $this->future = $future;
    }

    function setBooked($booked = NULL) {
        $this->booked = $booked;
    }

    function setStudent(\vendor\extension\Domain\Model\Student $student = NULL) {
        $this->student = $student;
    }

    function setExpertise(\vendor\extension\Domain\Model\Expertise $expertise = NULL) {
        $this->expertise = $expertise;
    }

}
```

And the corresponding fluid form:

```
<f:form action="list" name="appointmentFilter" 
            class="filter-form" 
            object="{appointmentFilter}" 
            arguments="{students:students,expertises:expertises}">  
        Termine:
        <label>
            <f:form.radio property="future" value="1"/> Bevorstehende
            <f:form.radio property="future" value="0"/> Vergangene
        </label>
        <label>
            <f:form.radio property="booked" value="2"/> Alle
            <f:form.radio property="booked" value="1"/> Gebuchte
            <f:form.radio property="booked" value="0"/> Freie
        </label>
        <label>
            Studenten:
            <f:form.select property="student" options="{students}" optionLabelField="fullName" prependOptionLabel="Alle Studenten" class="filterSelect" />                 
        </label>
        <label>
            Expertise:
            <f:form.select property="expertise" options="{expertises}" optionLabelField="name" prependOptionLabel="Alle" class="filterSelect" />
        </label>

        <f:form.submit value="Filter anwenden" class="rm-with-js" />
    </f:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description this is a caching problem. You can set your action to be noncachable by adding it in the second array in the plugin configuration in the localconf.php. Example:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi1',
    array(
        'Controller' => 'list, cachedAction',
    ),
    // this is the array for noncachable actions
    array(
        'Controller' => 'list',
    )
);
```

Comment: I thought this wasn't the problem because I already did that - but when I checked it turned out the extension builder had overwritten my settings so I had to set it again and it worked. There's this line in localconf.php: `## EXTENSION BUILDER DEFAULTS END TOKEN - Everything BEFORE this line is overwritten with the defaults of the extension builder` but I don't know if I can simply write the same thing after that line again without causing problems.